# c# wpf change properties of an object from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 windows on my project. For example, on first window, I have a label. I want to change the text of this label from other window.

```
        selectwindow win2 = new selectwindow();
        win2.Show();
```

with this command we can open another window. but how can we change a property of an object from another window?

Comment: That might depend on when you want to change the property in the other window.  Is there an event (such as user clicking a button) that would trigger the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes that inherit from Window can have their own properties and functions. Simply create a public function on your second Window class

```
public class SecondWindow:Window{
    public void UpdateSomething(string text) {
        //your code here
    } 
}
```

You can then call it in the first window with

```
var mywindow = new SecondWindow() 
mywindow.Show()
mywindow.UpdateSomething("your text")
```

But you should read more on C# to begin with because this is quite basic and you shouldn't call functions in such a way because it produces spaghetti code. You should read more about WPF and MVVM